# Let $f'$ be continuous. If $f$ is uniformly continuous then $f'$ is uniformly continuous?

Tags: real-analysis, calculus

Is this, in general, true? I need this in order to prove that a polynomial is uniformly continuous in $\mathbb{R}$ if and only if $p(x)$ is of degree less or equal to 1. If $p(x)$ is of degree less or equal to 1, is easy to prove that is uniform. Now, if $p(x)$ is of degree greater than one, then is not uniform. I want to proceed by induction, for degree greater or equal to 2, if $p(x)$ is of degree 2, is not uniforn. Then by induction $p'(x)$ is not uniform, and therefore $p(x)$ is not uniform either.

Answer (score 3):

Consider $f(x) = \sqrt{x}$ defined on $(0,1)$. Here, $f$ is differentiable with derivative $f'(x) = \frac{1}{2\sqrt{x}}$, and it is uniformly continuous because it is uniformly continuous on $[0,1]$, as this set is compact and $f$ continuous.

However, we can pick $x_n \to 0$ such that $f'(x_n) \to \infty$. In particular, $(x_n)_n$ is Cauchy but $(f'(x_n))_n$ is not, and thus $f'$ is not uniformly continuous.

Answer (score 1):

This is a modification of the example by Guido A wherein the function is defined on the whole line: take $f(x)=\sqrt {\frac {\pi} 2 +\tan^{-1}x}$. [Note that $f'$ is unbounded].